# How to output all data from one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to output all data from a give value1 to value2. My code is running but it only shows one data.

```
<?php 

  mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("NO connection");
  mysql_select_db("ci")or die("No DATABASE");

  $value1 =$_POST['value1'];
  $value2 =$_POST['value2'];
  $output="";

  if (isset($value1,$value2)){

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slogs WHERE stime BETWEEN 
            '". $value1 ."'AND '". $value2 ."' ");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count==0){
      $output='NO DATA IN DATABASE';
    }

    if ($count>1){
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
      { 
        $TIME=$row['stime'];
        $DT=$row['DT'];
        $FN=$row['FN'];
        $LN=$row['LN'];
      }
    }

  }

?>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but `mysql_` functions are deprecated and you should be escaping your post values before putting them inside a query.

Comment: It may be becuase you didn't provide space before AND in "' AND '"

Comment: `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`

Comment: edit with print_r($row)

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your query like this

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `slogs` WHERE stime BETWEEN 
 '". $value1 ."' AND '". $value2 ."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Then Try this way; within `while` loop, every time you are `overriding` your data to same variables

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
    printf("Time: %s  Date: %s FN: %s LN: %s", $row["stime"],$row["DT"],$row["FN"],$row["LN"]); 
}`
```